# How to scale writings in your DB without recurring to sharding?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, scaling, sharding

How would you scale writings without recurring to sharding (specially with SQL Server 2008)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not shard? The complexities in the code can be avoided by using transparent sharding tools, which ease all the heavy lifting associated with sharding. 
Check out [ScaleBase](http://sharding.scalebase.com) for more info

Answer (score 2):

Normally ... avoid indexes and foreign keys in big tables. Every insert/update on a indexed column implies rebuilding partially the index and sometimes this can be very costly. Of course, you'll have to trade query speed VS writing speed but this is a known issue in database design. You can combine this with a NoSQL database with a some sort of mechanism for caching queries. Maybe a fast NoSQL system sitting in front of your transactional system.

Another option is to use transactions in order to do many writes in one go, when you commit the transaction the indexes will be rebuilt but just once per transaction not one per write.

Comment: The transaction trick is pretty good thanks :)

You mean a NoSQL caching reading queries right?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. There was a typo.